# how to prevent casade on updates

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm working in grails and I've noticed some strange behavior to which I'd like to fix but I cannot figure out what I'm missing. 
I have a location which can have may buildings. Each building can have multiple suites.
In addition I have a tenant who has a tenant location.  The tenant location is used more for historical reporting so that we can see if tenants have moved locations. 
The classes look like this

```
class Location {

    String name
    String shortName
    Country country
    LocationTypeEnum locationType = LocationTypeEnum.STUD // as default

    static hasMany = [building: Building]

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        name unique: true, maxSize: 30
        shortName unique: true, maxSize: 3
        country nullable: false
        locationType nullable: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache usage: 'nonstrict-read-write', include: 'non-lazy'
    }
}

class Building {
    String type
    String name
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [location: Location]
    static hasMany = [suites: Suite]

    static constraints = {
        name unique: true, maxSize: 25
        type inList: ["A", "B", "C"], nullable: true
    }

    String toString() {
        name
    }
}

class Suite {
    int suiteNumber
    Date dateCreated

    static belongsTo = [building: Building]

    static constraints = {

        pen(validator: { return it > 0 && (it.toString().length()) <= 3 })

    }

    String toString() {
        suite.toString()
    }
}

class Tenant {

    static hasMany = [tenantLocation: TenantLocation]

    ----
    Suite suite
    String comments
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    boolean active = true

    static constraints = {
        --------
        type
        nullable: false
        comments maxSize: 5000

    }

}

class TenantLocation {
    static belongsTo = [tenant: Tenant]
    Tenant tenant
    Suite suite
    Date dateCreated
}
```

So the idea is that a tenant location is created when tenant is created and a new tenantLocation is created only if and when the current tenant suite changes.

However, what I'm seeing is not only is the tenantLocation being saved (which is what I want) the suite is also being updated (which is not what I want).

For example I have Building 1 and suites 1 - 20 and Building 2 with suites 1 - 25.  I have a tenant that is in Building 1 suite 5, they move to Building 2 suite 23. Now all of a sudden Building 2 has two suites with a suite number of 5.

How do I keep my suites from moving from one building to another when I only want the suite the tenant has to change?

The Code that is doing the updating is in the Tenant Controller and looks like this:

```
def update() {
    def tenantInstance = Tenant.get(params.id)

    if (!tenantInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [
            message(code: 'tenant.label', default: 'Tenant'),
            params.id
        ])
        redirect action: "list"
        return
    }

    if (params.version) {
        def version = params.version.toLong()
        if (tenantInstance.version > version) {
            tenantInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                    [
                        message(code: 'tenantInstance.label', default: 'Tenant')] as Object[],
                    "Another user has updated this Tenant while you were editing")
            render view: "edit", model: [tenantInstance: tenantInstance, BuidingListInstance: Building.list()]
            return
        }
    }

    tenantInstance.properties = params

    if (!tenantInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render view: "edit", model: [tenantInstance: tenantInstance, BuildingListInstance: Building.list()]
        return
    }


    def tenantLocation= TenantLocation.findAllByTenant(tenantInstance)
    def locationCheck = tenantLocation.last()



    //if tenant location is not null and the suite/building change create new Tenant Location entry
    if (tenantLocation!=null)
    {
        if(locationCheck.pen.id !=tenantInstance.suite.id)
        {

            def location = new TenantLocation(
                    tenant: tenantInstance,
                    suite: tenantInstance.suite,
                    dateCreated: new Date()
                    ).save(flush:true)
        }

    }



    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [
        message(code: 'tenant.label', default: 'Tenant'),
        tenantInstance.id
    ])
    redirect action: "show", id: tenantInstance.id
}
```

Comment: How are you updating the tenant location? Add that code to question.

Comment: I added the Update method from the controller per request.  I think it might have something to do with the properties = params command but am not sure